# How to get rid of a size warning in R for package development

Tags: r

I am working on submitting an `R` package and when I run

```
devtools::check()
```

I get the following warning:

```
W  checking sizes of PDF files under ‘inst/doc’ (1.6s)
     ‘gs+qpdf’ made some significant size reductions:
        compacted ‘Vignette1.pdf’ from 544Kb to 256Kb
        compacted ‘Vignette2.pdf’ from 328Kb to 69Kb
     consider running tools::compactPDF(gs_quality = "ebook") on these files
```

I understand that the size of the PDFs are the issue, and that they need to be resized, but can anyone explain to me where I need to place `tools::compactPDF(gs_quality = "ebook")` in my code so that when the vignettes are created this is not an issue.  You cannot submit an R package that throws a warning so I need to come up with a solution to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do `R CMD build --help` you will see the two lines

```
--compact-vignettes=  try to compact PDF files under inst/doc:  
                      "no" (default), "qpdf", "gs", "gs+qpdf", "both"
```

Per recent discussion on the mailing lists, you may want arguments `gs+qpdf` or `both`.  You may want to experiment with both.  Use of the option should render a package that does not trigger the NOTE.

And I presume there is a way to pass that onto `devtools` as well but I am not familiar with its functions so I can't give you a direct pointer.

Comment: Thanks! That's makes sense, and I never use the command line (I've just been using Rstudio and devtools) which is why that didn't occur to me.

Comment: In RStudio you can turn devtools use on/off and in the off' case can add to the existing options.  But knowing how stuff works on the command-line _is_ important.  Or so I try to tell my students ;-)

Comment: I'll give it the old college effort! Command line here I come! Thanks Dirk.

Comment: Not sure the relevance of devtools updates timeline - your answer doesn't address devtools aside from saying you're not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2):

As of devtools 2.4.5

```
devtools::check(build_args = "--compact-vignettes=gs+qpdf")
```

is the correct parameterization. But note that for *building*, the corresponding call is now

```
devtools::build(args = "--compact-vignettes=gs+qpdf")
```

Note that in neither case do you quote the argument passed down to R CMD BUILD's --compact-vignettes